# How to structure my c code to build up functionality

Tags: c, header

I am new to the c programming language and saw from another post that header guards are not preserved once a header file is included into another header. I think this means that I would have symbol redefinition problems if I were to include that second header file into a third header. I decided to try it using the sample code from the other post and yes I do get the error. I’ve attached the code below. Does this error arise because foo.h holds definitions instead of just declarations? Should the definition of the structures defined in foo.h been in foo.c? If so, what approach should I use to have several compilation units building on functionality of the previous?  In a stack architecture how do the layers access the functionality of a previous layer (do they include header files or follow some other approach)?

```
/*
 * foo.h
 *
 */

#ifndef FOO_H_
#define FOO_H_

#include  "stdint.h"

uint8_t test();

typedef struct regVal{
    uint16_t add;
    uint8_t val;
}reg;

const struct regVal regArr[] =
 {
     {0x3103,0x03},
     {0x3008,0x82},
     {0xFFFF,0xFF}
 };

#endif /* FOO_H_ */
```

---

```
/*
 * foo.c
 */

#include "foo.h"
#include  "stdint.h"

uint8_t test();


uint8_t test(){
    return 0x01;
}
```

---

```
/*
 * foo2.h
 *
 */

#ifndef FOO2_H_
#define FOO2_H_

#include "foo.h"
#include  "stdint.h"



#endif /* FOO2_H_ */
```

---

```
/*
 * foo3.h
 *
 */

#ifndef FOO3_H_
#define FOO3_H_

#include "foo2.h"
#include "stdint.h"



#endif /* FOO3_H_ */
```

---

```
/*
 * foo3.c
 */

#include "foo3.h"
#include "stdint.h"
```

And here is the linker error

```
 >symbol "regArr" redefined: first defined in "./foo.obj"; redefined in "./foo3.obj" null: symbol "regArr" redefined: first defined in "./foo.obj"; redefined in "./foo3.obj"
```

Comment: You header guards are OK and the problem you have is unrelated to header guards. Global variables must be declared in .c files and not in header files. In your case it's `regArr` that should be declared e.g. in `foo3.c`

Comment: could I declare the regArr in foo.c instead?

Comment: Yes you can declare in in the C file where it is needed.

Comment: @kial no, you have to *define* it, not just to *declare* it (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

> symbol "regArr" redefined: first defined in "./foo.obj"; redefined in "./foo3.obj" null: symbol "regArr" redefined: first defined in "./foo.obj"; redefined in "./foo3.obj"

in the headers you just have to declare variables and functions, not to define them (this is possible if the file is #included only one time but this is a bad choice)

*foo.h* is *#included* several times, and each time you define again *regArr*

so move

```
const struct regVal regArr[] =
{
     {0x3103,0x03},
     {0x3008,0x82},
     {0xFFFF,0xFF}
};
```

int *foo.c*

Comment: Hi Bruno. thank you very much for the clarifications

Comment: @kial, if you only *declare* it (rather than to *define* it) you will have the opposite error : symbol not found (rather than redefined)

Comment: Hi Bruno. thank you very much for the clarifications. when I move the regArry[] into foo.c should the foo.h contain its declaration like this const struct regVal regArr[]: ??

Comment: @kial all depend if _regArr_ is used elsewhere. If _regArr_ is only used in _foo.c_ do not declare it in _foo.h_, else declare it in _foo.h_

Comment: unfornutately it is used else where. How is the interface to const struct regVal regArry[] declared in foo.h?

Comment: const struct regVal regArr[]; is taken as a definition not as a declaration.

Comment: @kial `extern const struct regVal regArr[3];`

Comment: I successfully declared it as const struct regVal *regName;

Comment: I have many array types of different sizes. Could I use const struct regVal *regName; and then access the struct using const struct regVal regArr[] from a different compilation unit which included foo.h?

Comment: @kial yes you can

Comment: I tried to vote but I am a newbie without sufficient experience

Comment: @kial to vote for an answer just click on the up arrow on its top (with number 0 currently)

Comment: @kial  Voting is different from [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).  Any user can accept an answer to his question by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer you wish to accept.

Answer (score 0):

Well let me first explain that what is a compilation unit. In c every single .c file is compiled separately to get a .o file and then all the .o files are linked to make the final executable.

Now lets see how include files are treated. All include files that are included in a c file get copied in that c file in the preprocessing stage. To see this you can run 
    gcc -E your-c-file.c -o out.i
And you can examine the out file to see what i mean.

So when you include foo.h in foo.c it gets included and during compilation stage a instance of regArr[] is created.
Now when foo3.c is compiled another instance of regArr[] is created in this compilation unit because ultimately foo.h gets included in it too. Note that all compilation units are independent. Now when the linker tries to link both object files it throws this error because in c no two variables or functions can have same name.

Comment: so if I move the regArr[] into foo.c and simply declare its interface in foo.h then it won't be compiled in downstream compilation units. Your explanation makes very good sense and I am going to try it. Thank you very much for taking the trouble to help me. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I think extern qualifier will help you in this. In c when we want to access the functions that are defined in other files we simply declare them to tell the compiler that they will be resolved in the linker stage but for variables we use extern keyword. So in foo.c you declare the variable and when you want to access it in an other file you just put the extern keyword before that to tell the compiler that be patient this exist in an other compilation unit and linker will resolve it.

Comment: can I use "extern const struct regVal *regName; "  and provide the fill *regName with regArr[] when accessing it from another unit?

Comment: I looked at the link you sent. It recommends - All what is visible in other files is defined in h file (eg typedef struct {...} is in h file if is used by two or more c files). Global (used all over c files) are in global.h.  Isn't this the problem I am trying to avoid?

Comment: It says that the struct defination remains in the header file and create the instances in c files. So that when you do extern const struct regVal *regVal; in foo3.c it does not complain about the undefined struct type regVal.

Comment: Let me make it clear. See you want to access the variable declared in one c file in another c file right. So what you do is define the struct in foo.h and create its instance in foo.c and create its declaration using extern const struct regVal *regVal; in foo3.c and then you can access it in foo3.c without compiler complaining

Comment: Please forgive me, I am still confused. If I define the struct in the foo.h won't that lead to symbol redefinition downstream? Or does the extern const struct regBal *regArr prevent the definition from being copied into the c file each time?